# WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.faces.flow.FlowScoped

Tags: jsf, cdi, glassfish-4.1, faces-flow

Just started doing my first steps with FacesFlow with Glassfish 4.1 (i.e. using Mojarra) and when invoking my flow I get an error named

```
[SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] ...  Error Rendering View[/register/register.xhtml]
org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.faces.flow.FlowScoped
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getContext(BeanManagerImpl.java:708)
```

Several others had that error too as I can see in the web but the solutions that worked for other somehow dont work for me (see below).

I also tried `@SessionScoped` which works. So it is related to `@FlowScoped`.

To what I read in a book that I use to get me up to speed I should be ok from coding and config end since according to API `@FlowScoped` is CDI based and I use the following code at my backing bean/controller.

```
@Named
@FlowScoped(value="register")
public class RegisterController implements Serializable {
```

I have a flow named register whose pages are located in a dirctory /register and the first page of the flow is named register.xhtml

Following snippet I tried both as a `register/register-flow.xml` config file as well as `WEB-INF/faces-config.xml` without success.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">
    <flow-definition id="register">
        <flow-return id="overview">
            <from-outcome>/index</from-outcome>
        </flow-return>
    </flow-definition>
</faces-config>
```

What I tried so far:
I found a post suggesting that `<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/PROJEST_NAME"/>` would solve the problem but after googling the tag it turns out its an outdated Tomcat tag.

Changing `@Named` to `@ManagedBean` didn't really help as suggested on one page. I could open the pages but the data in my controller class would not be available when invoking the next page of the flow anymore. But `@ManagedBean` shouldn't really work I guess since `@FlowScoped` is CDI based.

Another post suggested to ensure that `javax.faces.CLIENT_WINDOW_MODE` is enabled. I tried that via adding the following to my web.xml but without success

```
<context-param>
<param-name>javax.faces.CLIENT_WINDOW_MODE</param-name>
<param-value>url</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Another suggested to use Glassfish 4.x which I already do

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a sample app that can reproduce this?

Answer (score -2):

With Glassfish 4.1 at least you need to add the **cdi-api.jar** directory library.

Glassfish includes the *weld-osgi-bundle.jar* but it also needs *cdi-api.jar* to work because the **CDI bean scopes** aren't in the `weld-osgi...` so make sure you have it if not its here:

`[gf_installation_path]/glassfish/modules/cdi-api.jar`

This will give you access to the packages used with `CDI Beans` i.e., `javax.enterprise.context.*`

If not then probably

1. [this could help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10994901/2940051)
2. [and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22178375/flow-scope-navigation-to-start-page-does-not-work)

GL!